# Using ReplaceTextWithMapping with multiple columns in mapping file

Tags: regex, replace, apache-nifi

I would need to clarify the usage of ReplaceTextWithMapping in NiFi in my specific case. My input file looks like this:

```
{"field1" : "A",
"field2" : "A",
"field3": "A"
}
```

The mapping file looks, instead, like this:

```
 Header1;Header2;Header3
 A;some text;2
```

My expected result would be as follows:

```
   {"field1" : "some text",
    "field2": "A",
    "field3": "A2"
    }
```

The Regular Expression set is simply as follows:

```
[A-Z0-9]+
```

and it matches the field key in the mapping file (we are expecting either a capital letter or capital letter + digit), but then I am not sure how you decided to which value (from col 2 or from col3) you want to assign the input value to. Also, my field2 should not changed and needs retaining the same value it is getting from the input value, with no mapping involved. At the moment, I am getting something like this:

```
  {"field1" : "some text A2",
    "field2": "some text A2",
    "field3": "some text A2"
    }
```

I guess my main question is: can you mapped the same value in your input file with different values coming from different column of your mapping file?

Thank you

EDIT: I am using [ReplaceTextWithMapping](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/index.html), an out-of-the-box processor in Apache NiFi (v. 0.5.1). Throughout my dataflow, I end up with a Json file on which I need to apply some mappings coming from external files I would like to load in memory (rather than parse using ExtractText, for example).

Answer (score 2):

## Forward

It appears that you're working with a JSON string, it would be easier to work with such a string via a JSON parsing engine as the JSON structure allows the creation of difficult edge cases that makes parsing with regular expressions difficult. With that said, I'm sure you have your reasons, and I'm not the Regex Police.

## Description

To do such a replacement it would be easier to capture the substrings you'll keep and the substrings you want to replace.

`(\{"[a-z0-9]+"\s*:\s*")([a-z0-9]+)("[,\r\n]+"[a-z0-9]+"\s*:\s*")([a-z0-9]+)("[,\r\n]+"[a-z0-9]+"\s*:\s*")([a-z0-9]+)("[,\r\n]+\})`

Replace with: `$1SomeText$3$4$5A2$7`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: I recommend using the following flags with this expression: Case Insensitive, and Dot matches all characters including new lines.

## Exmaples

**Live Deno**

This example shows how the regular expression matches against your source text: 
https://regex101.com/r/vM1qE2/1

**Source Text**

```
{"field1" : "A",
"field2" : "A",
"field3": "A"
}
```

**After Replacement**

```
{"field1" : "SomeText",
"field2" : "A",
"field3": "A2"
}
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\r\n]+                 any character of: ',', '\r' (carriage
                             return), '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\r\n]+                 any character of: ',', '\r' (carriage
                             return), '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \7:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\r\n]+                 any character of: ',', '\r' (carriage
                             return), '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \}                       '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \7
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your very detailed response, much appreciated. I am actually using a NiFi processor called ReplaceTextWithMapping (see here:  https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/index.html) and I seem to be able to use matching groups (Matching group property), although it seems I can only set one at a time. I have made a few attempts, but it does not work in NiFi.

Comment: The doc for ReplaceTextWithMapping says the replace systax is a number without a dollarsign. I recommend having a look at ReplaceText which uses the dollarsign + Number combo for replace values. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html

Comment: Yeah, that was my first step, but moved to ReplaceTextWithMapping because through my dataflow I need to apply some mappings coming from external files. That is why I am using ReplaceTextWithMapping and I am not sure if I am missing anything, but it does not seem to be possible to work with multiple matching groups. Thank you for your help, appreciated.

Comment: I just posted an answer that addresses the question with the understanding that a map file is necessary.  @RoYoMi I very much appreciate the detailed response as well but that being said, I down-voted it since it doesn't address the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

So I dove into ReplaceTextWithMapping to try and get it to solve your use-case but I just don't think it is powerful enough to do what you want. Currently it is designed almost solely for the purpose: match a simple regex, map one group of non-whitespace characters to another group of characters (can have white space and back references).

When looking at your use-case as pure text, it is to change the value of one capture group based on the value of another capture group and a mapping file. Looking at it in terms of JSON, your use-case is much simpler, you want to change the value of a key/value pair based on what the key is and a mapping file. Side note, if you didn't need the mapping file, I believe there is a new JSON to JSON processor coming in 0.7.0[1] that would work.

As for looking for a solution, both ways of looking at your problem are valid. ReplaceTextWithMapping certainly could use expanded functionality to allow for advanced use-cases but may make it too complicated (though it could be more confusing now due to the unclear scope of it's functionality). A new processor, along the lines of "ReplaceJsonWithMapping" could certainly be added as well but would need to clearly define it's scope and purpose.

Also for a more immediate solution there is always the option to use the ExecuteScript processor. Here[2] is a link to blog (written by the creator of ExecuteScript) which outlines how to write a basic JSON-to-JSON processor. There would need to be more logic added to have the ability to read a file for the mapping.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-361
[2] http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-json-to-json-conversion.html