# Nifi: Change the same values of all elements in an array (e.g. test="nio" => test=0)

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

*Edit1: Any number of new attributes with the same name can be added, for which the value is also to be changed. Therefore, several attributes with the same name and the same value can occur, which must all be exchanged. Therefore it should be dynamic.*

I can no longer get on in Nifi at the following point. I would like to change the values of certain attributes in an array on the same basis. In my case, for example, the following change would be desired:

***test="nio"*** => ***test=0***

***test="io"*** => ***test=1***

My first guess is to implement this with JOLT, but I currently lack any approach in this regard.

Input:

```json
{
  "counterTop": {
    "loaf1": [
      {
        "type": "white",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "nio"
      },
      {
        "type": "black",
        "unit": "cm",
        "test": "io"
      },
      {
        "type": "black123",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "io"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "counterTop": {
    "loaf1": [
      {
        "type": "white",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "0"
      },
      {
        "type": "black",
        "unit": "cm",
        "test": "1"
      },
      {
        "type": "black123",
        "unit": "mm",
        "test": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone here have a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to use simple ReplaceText processor. It will be straight forward and probably will give you even better performance compared to JSON operations.

Comment: Oh yeah, that could be working. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide upto the innermost by roaming through `"*"` wildcards firstly, then conquer by combining within `counterTop.loaf1[&..]` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "counterTop.loaf1[&1].&",
            "test": {
              "nio": {
                "@(2,&1)": { "*": { "#0": "counterTop.loaf1[&].&4" } }
              },
              "io": {
                "@(2,&1)": { "*": { "#1": "counterTop.loaf1[&].&4" } }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where the rightmost `.&4` represents going 4 level up in order to reach the key `test`, and the rightmost `.&` represents the values for the rest of the keys.

**Edit :** Considering your last case with multiple elements, you can prefer using the following instead of the above one as a generic case

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "loaf1[&1].&",
            "test": {
              "nio": {
                "@(2,&1)": { "*": { "#0": "&4" } }
              },
              "io": {
                "@(2,&1)": { "*": { "#1": "&4" } }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": "counterTop.loaf1[&].&1",
        "@(1,loaf1)": "counterTop.loaf1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help again! It is really quite tricky. With your solution there is still the following problem, as soon as there are several times e.g. test="nio", then this is summarized later to an array and thus the output changes in a wrong way.

Comment: Hi @kingsven149 , you're welcome. Can you please edit the question in order to add the problematic  case you have met.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, I edited the question with a better explanation of my problematic case.

Comment: yes, you're right, I've added the generic case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very greatful for your great and fast help!

Comment: you're welcome @kingsven149 , have a nice study

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to achieve this with ReplaceText processor:
[image]
Pay attention to the replace text configuration: [image]
Downside of such approach is that you need separate processor for every mapping. To overcome it, you can use ReplaceTextWithMapping, here is a great [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237848/using-replacetextwithmapping-with-multiple-columns-in-mapping-file)

Comment: Thanks. In the end, the difficult part was only the regex.